# How to solve the differential equation for power series $(1+x^2)y'' - 6xy=0$ for $x_{0}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have tried for the power series but when suppose the solution is $y(x)=\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ appeared sums dependents of $a_n$, $a_{n+2}$ and $a_{n-1}$ and this is not possible.

assume $y(x)=\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ solution,  so

$ y'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$ and $y''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$

then the equation $(1+x^2)y'' - 6xy=0$ is:

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty 6a_nx^{n+1}=0$

We can shift the dummy indices, taking k=n−2 in the first sum, k=n in the second sum and k=n+1 in the last sum:

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}x^k+\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)a_{k}x^k- \sum_{k=1}^\infty6a_{k-1}x^k=0$

taking $k=0$ and $k=1$, we have $2a_{2}=0$ so $a_2=0$ and $ 6a_3x-6a_0x=0$ so $a_3=a_0$. For $k>1$ we have

$(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2} + k(k-1)a_k - 6a_{k-1}=0$

so

$a_k=\frac{ 6a_{k-1} -(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2} }{k(k-1)}$

and $a_2=0, a_3=a_0$.

but this recorrence not determines the solution cause $a_k$ depends of $a_{k-1}$ and $a_{k+2}$.

Comment: Could you share the equations that you obtained that relate the $a_n$ together? Why would they be not possible?

Comment: What are your initial conditions (there should be two, for this to be an IVP with unique solution).

Comment: You have to be very careful in how you juggle terms for power series solutions. Show us what you got!

Comment: solve for $a_{k+2}$ instead of $a_k$